# how to get other elements along with arrayToObject in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get the count of all the different value of a key in my MongoDB. I am getting the count as well but I need other details as well along with the count.

```
   {hobby:"swimming", "name" : "abc", "state" : 'PA', "age":10, "address":"ggg"}
   {hobby:"swimming", "name" : "abc", "state" : 'PA', "age":10, "address":"ggg" }
   {hobby:"swimming", "name" : "def", "state" : 'IA', "age":12, "address":"kkk"  }
   {hobby:"swimming", "name" : "def", "state" : 'IA', "age":12, "address":"kkk"   }
   {hobby:"swimming", "name" : "abc", "state" : 'DA', "age":10, "address":"ggg"  }
   {hobby:"swimming", "name" : "abc", "state" : 'DA', "age":10, "address":"India"  }
   {hobby:"swimming", "name" : "def", "state" : 'DA', "age":12, "address":"kkk"   }
   {hobby:"swimming", "name" : "abc", "state" : 'IA', "age":10, "address":"ggg"  }


     return db.collection.aggregate([
        {"$match":{"hobby":"swimming"}},
        {"$group":
          {
             "_id":{"name":"$name","state":"$state","age":"$age","address":"$address"},
             "count":{"$sum":1}
           }
        },
        {"$group":{
            "_id":"$_id.name",
            "age":"$_id.age",
           "address":"$_id.address",
           "details":{
                "$push":{
                   "k":"$_id.state",
                   "v":"$count"
                }
             }
         }},
         {"$addFields":{
            "details":{
                "$arrayToObject":"$details"
             }
          }}
      ])
```

Current Result:-

Unhandled Rejection at: MongoError: The field 'age' must be an accumulator object

Expected Result:-

```
[
  {
     "_id": "def",
     "age":10,
     "address":"ggg",
     "details": {
       "DA": 1,
       "IA": 2
     }
  },
 {
     "_id": "abc",
     "age":12,
     "address":"kkk",
     "details": {
        "DA": 2,
        "IA": 1,
        "PA": 2
     }
  }
]
```

Anyone any idea how to get this?

Answer (score 1):

The error

> Unhandled Rejection at: MongoError: The field 'age' must be an
>   accumulator object

is come when we try to get an object(key value) from same object list mostly in the group when groupBy in MongoDB

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": { "hobby": "swimming" }
  },
  { "$group": {
      "_id": { "name": "$name", "state": "$state", 
                "age": "$age", "address": "$address"},
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.name",
      "age": { $first: "$_id.age" },       
      "address": { $first: "$_id.address" },
      "details": {
        "$push": { "k": "$_id.state", "v": "$count" }
       }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "details": { "$arrayToObject": "$details" }
    }
  }
])
```

This line of code is wrong because their are more then object to get an age or address element from them

```
"age": "$_id.age",       
"address": "$_id.address",
```

So now we choose [first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) object

```
"age": { $first: "$_id.age" },       
"address": { $first: "$_id.address" },
```

You can check [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R8QypxqkEm3)